# Why did Orson Welles say, "Shoot-out at the O.K. Corral"?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

At the end of the movie *Mank* (2020), holding clipboard with his hand, director
Orson Welles visits his writer Mank's:

> Orson Welles: Rise and shine, hombre. **Shoot-out at the O.K. Corral**.
> Before we buckle down, I gather you have something to  get off your
> chest?

Why did Orson Welles say, "Shoot-out at the O.K. Corral"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The gunfight at the O.K. Corral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunfight_at_the_O.K._Corral) was a settling of accounts between the Earps and the Clantons (and their henchmen, known as "The Cowboys"). About thirty shots were fired in thirty seconds. It was sudden, brutal and merciless. It was almost the final episode of a competitive rivalry.

Now, if you see Orson Welles and Mank on one side, and WR Hearst and LB Mayer on the other side, imagine how nice and friendly the battle will be :)

I understand this as: "*are you ready to fight til the end, no matter what the issue might be?*".